# docker-compose: Connect container to "network=host" and to other services

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose

I struggle to achieve the following:

I want two have two `docker compose` services (let's call them `service_A` and `service_B`), where

- `service_A` needs to be in the host's network (i.e. runs with `network_mode=host`) and
- `service_B` can connect to `service_A` via its hostname, but it's also in the hosts network.

Here I made an example, which demonstrates what I want to achieve with `postgres` services as examples:

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  service_A:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
    network_mode: host  

  service_B:
    image: postgres
    depends_on:
      - service_A
    network_mode: host 
    command: psql postgresql://postgres:password@service_A:5432 --command "select * from pg_tables limit 1;"
```

But, when setting `network_mode=host` on `service_A` and `service_B`, `service_B` cannot reach `service_A` via its hostname. Is there an easy way to achieve that?

For those, who are interested why I need such a setup:

- `service_A` functions as a proxy and logs into a VPN (via the docker host's connection)
- and `service_B` shouldn't see the whole docker host, but needs to read from `service_A`, but be also responsive on the docker host.

Comment: If you bash into service_b can you ping service_a?

Comment: `network_mode: host` generally disables Docker's networking layer; you can't combine it with other network options.  If `service_B` ran on a normal Docker bridge network, it could connect to `service_A` the same as any other host-based process.